# Android custom view and visible button

Tags: android, button, view

I made my custom view and I want to add view.button, so I made this solution:

```
Public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Button up;
    up = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    up.setText("ahoj");
    up.setHeight(100);
    up.setWidth(100);
    up.setTop(200);
    up.setLeft(100);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout);

    myview view = new myview(this);
    layout.addView(view);

layout.addView(up);
```

I only see my view but no button. My view only draw some PNG file. Does anyone know where is the problem? Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason is that your custom view is added with layout params `MATCH_PARENT`.  It takes the whole of the layout and the button is not visible.  Try instead adding your custom view with `WRAP_CONTENT` params:

```
MyView view = new myview(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LAYOUTParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
layout.addView(view, lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the code right but in the wrong order. Try this:

```
Public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Button up;
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    up = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    up.setText("ahoj");
    up.setHeight(100);
    up.setWidth(100);
    up.setTop(200);
    up.setLeft(100);




    myview view = new myview(this);
    layout.addView(view);
    layout.addView(up);

    setContentView(layout);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: Adding views to the layout after calling `setContentView` is perfectly acceptable.  I don't think the problem is with the order.  Also, ideally, you should call `super.onCreate` in the very beginning of your method, not at the very end.